# Update Categories in Hybris for products

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have several products with different super categories assign in Hybris.

I add the super categories to these products via impex.

```
$supercategories=supercategories(code,$catalogVersion)
UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];$catalogVersion[unique=true];supercategories(code,$catalogVersion)[mode=append]
;ProductName;;1017
;ProductName1;;1017
```

I'm wondering if there's a way I can defined which super category goes first at the moment I'm assigning the categories to the products, or an update to decide which one goes first.

So in few words, I will need super category 368 to be the first one.

```
Currently is         New Result
297                    368
368                    686  
686                    297
```

[image]

Comment: Which goes first, in the sense? Are you talking about the order in which categories are getting displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the relation to enable `ordered="true"` for supercategories.

> ordered="boolean" [0..1]
>
> If 'true' an additional ordering attribute will be generated for maintaining ordering. Default is 'false'.

OOTB :

```
<relation code="CategoryProductRelation" autocreate="true" generate="true" localized="false">
        <deployment table="Cat2ProdRel" typecode="143"/>
        <sourceElement qualifier="supercategories" type="Category" cardinality="many" ordered="false">
            <description>Super Categories</description>
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true"/>
        </sourceElement>
        <targetElement qualifier="products" type="Product" cardinality="many" collectiontype="list" ordered="true">
            <description>Products</description>
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true"/>
        </targetElement>        
    </relation>
```

TO :

```
<relation code="CategoryProductRelation" autocreate="true" generate="true" localized="false">
        <deployment table="Cat2ProdRel" typecode="143"/>
        <sourceElement qualifier="supercategories" type="Category" cardinality="many" ordered="true">
            <description>Super Categories</description>
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true"/>
        </sourceElement>
        <targetElement qualifier="products" type="Product" cardinality="many" collectiontype="list" ordered="true">
            <description>Products</description>
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true"/>
        </targetElement>        
    </relation>
```

I am not sure whether `redeclare=true` will work in relation tag or not, but since for supercategories order="false", order will not maintained until unless its true.